# Make Mono.NET works on ubuntu 10.04 SERVER

Tags: .net, mono, ubuntu-10.04

I am sorry by advance for my beginner question but in fact ... i am a beginner.

So let me explain you what i have already done and what i would like to obtain.

I have developed a WebService in C# .NET and i would like to make it run on a Ubuntu 10.04 SERVER

- I have install "mono-complete" with apt-get install mono-complete
- I have "published" my WebService on my var/www/.../ws to make it accessible from the web
- I have tried to use it and it does not work ....

See for example for example what i have : www.romain-richard.com/WS/

If you click on Default.aspx or another page, it not runs the page but it just shows it

So it is sure i make something wrong ! Is my project not correctly generated ? Is mono need any configuration before working ?

Thanks for help and feel free to ask me more informations !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 is very old, and that must include a very old version of Mono.

Ubuntu 12.04 on the other hand is new, it is LTS, and it includes a newer version of Mono.

Before anything else, I would upgrade the OS. You may be running into a bug of Mono that is already fixed in the last version.

If after upgrading your OS, you still have the same problem, then it is worth it to spend more time digging.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't that easy for a beginner, I'm not sure how up-to-date this is but try this:

http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono